# Line chart with radio button and multiple series

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, linechart

I would like to create a [line chart like this](http://bl.ocks.org/jhubley/17aa30fd98eb0cc7072f), with the difference of having radio buttons instead of a dropdown selector.

This is my **data.csv** file:

```
CODE,YEAR,MODALITY,VALUE
AB,2000,first,15
AB,2000,second,
AB,2000,third,33
AB,2001,first,20
AB,2001,second,25
AB,2001,third,87
AB,2002,first,6
AB,2002,second,
AB,2002,third,16
AC,2000,first,
AC,2000,second,97
AC,2000,third,77
AC,2001,first,42
AC,2001,second,5
AC,2001,third,81
AC,2002,first,
AC,2002,second,63
AC,2002,third,14
AD,2000,first,11
AD,2000,second,2
AD,2000,third,36
AD,2001,first,95
AD,2001,second,78
AD,2001,third,88
AD,2002,first,89
AD,2002,second,32
AD,2002,third,79
AE,2000,first,15
AE,2000,second,78
AE,2000,third,1
AE,2001,first,5
AE,2001,second,2
AE,2001,third,64
AE,2002,first,44
AE,2002,second,51
AE,2002,third,
```

As you can see, the file has missing data, the series aren't complete but may have "holes" in which `VALUE` is not defined.

Through an interface (here I don't show it because it is not useful) the user can choose which `CODEs` he wants. The aim is to create a line for each chosen `CODE`. These codes are saved in the `codes` array, which can have variable length (it can contain one or more elements).

In addition there are radio buttons that the user can use to choose the `MODALITY`.

Therefore, the data to be shown must be filtered for `MODALITY` (radio button) and for `CODE` (codes array).

This is my code:

**index.html**:

```
<body>
   <div id="modality-selector-container">
      <form id="modality-selector">
         <input type="radio" name="modality-selector" id="rb-first" value="first" checked />
         <label for="rb-first">First</label>
         <input type="radio" name="modality-selector" id="rb-second" value="second" />
         <label for="rb-second">Second</label>
         <input type="radio" name="modality-selector" id="rb-third" value="third" />
         <label for="rb-third">Third</label>
      </form>
   </div>

   <div id="line-chart-container"></div>
   <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**script.js**:

```
// variable array of codes. It can contain one or more codes, depending on the user
var codes = ['AE', 'AB'];
console.log("Codes: " + codes);
modalitySelected = document.querySelector('input[name=modality-selector]:checked').value; 

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50};
var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date/time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y"); 

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]); 

// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
   .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.YEAR); 
   })
   .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.VALUE);  
   });  

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("#line-chart-container").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.queue()
   .defer(d3.csv, './data.csv') 
   .await(makeLineChart); 

function makeLineChart(error, data) {
   if(error) {
      console.log(error);
   }

   // filter data
   var filtered_data = data.filter(function(d) {
      return d.MODALITY == modalitySelected && codes.includes(d.CODE);
      //return d.MODALITY == modalitySelected && d.CODE == codes[0];
   });
   console.log(filtered_data);

   var numTickXaxis = filtered_data.length;

   // format the data
   filtered_data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.YEAR = parseTime(d.YEAR);
      d.VALUE = +d.VALUE;
   });

   // scale the range of the data
   x.domain(d3.extent(filtered_data, function(d) { 
      return d.YEAR; 
   }));
   y.domain([0, d3.max(filtered_data, function(d) { 
      return d.VALUE; 
   })]);

   // add the valueline path
   svg.append("path")
      .data([filtered_data])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);

   // add the X Axis
   svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
         .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y"))
         .ticks(numTickXaxis))
      .selectAll("text")   
         .style("text-anchor", "end")
         .attr("dx", "-.8em")
         .attr("dy", ".15em")
         .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

   // add the Y Axis
   svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
}
```

**style.css**:

```
#modality-selector-container {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

#line-chart-container {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#line-chart-container svg {
    border: solid 1px black;
}

path.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
}
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/z9VLGWUknJlwMBonpl6A?p=preview) my partially working Plunker.

As you can see, the code works only for a set of values (in this case I chose the `AE` code, the first in the array).
But it should show two lines, one for the `AE` code and one for the `AB` code.
I have no idea how to do this, considering that it must be adaptive, since the array codes can be long at the user's will.

Also I can't manage updating the chart when the radio button changes.
I tried to follow the code found in the example but the result is not great.

**script.js**:

```
// variable array of codes. It can contain one or more codes, depending on the user
var codes = ['AE', 'AB']; 
console.log("Codes: " + codes);
modalitySelected = document.querySelector('input[name=modality-selector]:checked').value; 
var filtered_data = null;

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50};
var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date/time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y"); 

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]); 

// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
   .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.YEAR); 
   })
   .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.VALUE);  
   });  

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("#line-chart-container").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.queue()
   .defer(d3.csv, './data.csv') 
   .await(makeLineChart); 

function makeLineChart(error, data) {
   if(error) {
      console.log(error);
   }

   // radio button change
   d3.selectAll("input[name='modality-selector']")
      .on("change", function(){
         console.log(this.value);
         modalitySelected = this.value;

         // filter data
         filtered_data = data.filter(function(d) {
            return d.MODALITY == modalitySelected && d.CODE == codes[0];
         });

         // format the data
         filtered_data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.YEAR = parseTime(d.YEAR);
            d.VALUE = +d.VALUE;
         });

         updateGraph(filtered_data);
      }); // end radio on change

   // generate initial line chart - filter data
   filtered_data = data.filter(function(d) {
      return d.MODALITY == modalitySelected && d.CODE == codes[0];
   });
   updateGraph(filtered_data);  
} 

function updateGraph(data) {
   var numTickXaxis = data.length;

   // scale the range of the data
   x.domain(d3.extent(filtered_data, function(d) { 
      return d.YEAR; 
   }));
   y.domain([0, d3.max(filtered_data, function(d) { 
      return d.VALUE; 
   })]);

   // add the valueline path
   svg.append("path")
      .data([filtered_data])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);

   // add the X Axis
   svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
         .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y"))
         .ticks(numTickXaxis))
      .selectAll("text")   
         .style("text-anchor", "end")
         .attr("dx", "-.8em")
         .attr("dy", ".15em")
         .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

   // add the Y Axis
   svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y)); 

   var state = svg.selectAll(".line");
   state.exit().remove();
}
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/t0XcubIlyj7JSwDAhvGT?p=preview) the Plunker.

There are three problems:

1. in the case of default selection (so when the graph is loaded the first time), the line chart is not built correctly
2. when changing radio button selection, the graph is overwritten (despite the presence of `state.exit().remove();`)
3. when I select the same radio button for the second time, the **Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,0LNaN,341.02…"** error appears in the console (eg. at the beginning there is selected *First*, I select *Second*, I select *Third*, I select *Second* -> error).

Would anyone know how to help me? Thanks!

---

## UPDATE 1

As RobertAndersson suggested, I can consider having data saved in this way (which I think is even smarter, actually).

**data.csv**:

```
CODE,YEAR,FIRST,SECOND,THIRD
AB,2000,15,,33
AB,2001,20,25,87
AB,2002,6,,16
AC,2000,,97,77
AC,2001,42,5,81
AC,2002,,63,14
AD,2000,11,2,36
AD,2001,95,78,88
AD,2002,89,32,79
AE,2000,15,78,1
AE,2001,5,2,64
AE,2002,44,51,
```

In this case, how could I do?

---

## UPDATE 2

I hope to better explain what I need.

What I need, uses both the radio button selection (with value first, second or third) and an array of values AB, AC, AD, AE that can vary in number and combination.

Here an example.

In the upper part the user can select one or more circles (they are the AB, AC, AD and AE codes). Then click on Finish and the array `codes` is created and printed.

Then the user can select the desired radio button (first, second or third).

Based on these choices, the system should retrieve the correct data from the csv file and create the line chart.

For example:
[image]

The dotted line indicates that the data is missing.

I have updated the files.

**index.html**:

```
<body>
   <div id="circles">
      <svg>
         <circle id="AB" cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="purple" />
         <circle id="AC" cx="60" cy="60" r="5" fill="red" />
         <circle id="AD" cx="110" cy="110" r="15" fill="orange" />
         <circle id="AE" cx="90" cy="50" r="7" fill="yellow" />
      </svg>
   </div>
   <button type="button" id="finalSelection">Finish</button>

   <span style="display:block;margin-top: 10px;">Selected codes: <span class="values"></span></span><br>

   <div id="modality-selector-container">
      <form id="modality-selector">
         <input type="radio" name="modality-selector" id="rb-first" value="first" checked />
         <label for="rb-first">First</label>
         <input type="radio" name="modality-selector" id="rb-second" value="second" />
         <label for="rb-second">Second</label>
         <input type="radio" name="modality-selector" id="rb-third" value="third" />
         <label for="rb-third">Third</label>
      </form>
   </div>

   <div id="line-chart-container"></div>
   <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**script.js**:

```
/*****************************************************************************************/
/* CODE FOR SELECT ELEMENTS.
/*****************************************************************************************/

var codes = [];

d3.selectAll('#circles svg circle').on('click', function() {
   // fetch ID
   var id = d3.select(this).attr('id');

   // toggle "clicked" class and push/splice id within the codes array accordingly based on event.metaKey (CTRL)
   if(d3.select(this).classed('clicked')) { // classed add/remove a CSS class from the selection
      d3.select(this).classed('clicked', false).style('stroke', null);
      codes.splice(codes.indexOf(id), 1); // the splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s)
   } 
   else { // if an item has never been selected
      if(codes.length) { // if the array codes is not empty
         if(d3.event.ctrlKey) { // if CTRL is pressed
            d3.select(this).classed('clicked', true).style('stroke', 'blue');
            codes.push(id); 
         }
         else { // if the item I'm selecting has never been selected and before I had already selected other elements
            // I "remove" all those already selected
            d3.selectAll(".clicked").classed('clicked', false).style('stroke', null);
            codes = [];
            // I consider selected the one actually selected
            d3.select(this).classed('clicked', true).style('stroke', 'blue');
            codes.push(id); 
         }
      } 
      else { // if the array codes is empty
         d3.select(this).classed('clicked', true).style('stroke', 'blue');
         codes.push(id);
      }
   }

   $('span.values').html(codes.join(', '));
});

$('button#finalSelection').click(function() {
   $('span.values').html(codes.join(', '));
   console.log("compare: " + codes);
});

/*****************************************************************************************/
/* CODE FOR LINE CHART.
/*****************************************************************************************/

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");

// ...
```

**data.csv**:

```
CODE,YEAR,FIRST,SECOND,THIRD
AB,2000,15,50,33
AB,2001,20,25,87
AB,2002,6,,16
AB,2003,50,50,10
AB,2004,20,55,8
AC,2000,,97,77
AC,2001,42,5,81
AC,2002,,63,14
AC,2003,5,7,0
AC,2004,5,7,0
AD,2000,11,2,36
AD,2001,95,78,88
AD,2002,89,32,79
AD,2003,5,32,9
AD,2004,7,32,91
AE,2000,15,78,1
AE,2001,5,2,64
AE,2002,44,51,
AE,2003,40,52,85
AE,2004,45,50,80
```

[Here the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Iy5omTQ6TYmSzTaqD7Fn).

Comment: Does the csv data have to be the way it is or is it just test data? Because there are a lot more simpler ways of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: @RobertAndersson My data.csv is like this, it is only much longer because contains about 170000 entries

Comment: @RobertAndersson Could you help me?

Comment: @RobertAndersson Excuse me if I insist, what problems do my data have?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your data, I'm just unfamiliar with how I'd work around it, I'm more used to having "first", "second", "third" be thier own columns for example

Comment: @RobertAndersson I have modified the main message. Actually, I can edit my `data.csv` file and the way you suggest to save data, it's smarter, because I have less entries and the data are less repeated. So meanwhile I thank you very much for this suggestion :) If you help me, I would be grateful. Because I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I think your question is a bit too unfocused, if you ask **one** question at a time that you need help with I think that you'd get more help, and if you need further help you just post another question. I'd delete this & rephrase your question so that you're asking only one thing.

Comment: I created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264567/how-to-create-a-multiseries-line-chart-using-data-filtered-from-a-csv-file). I hope it goes well this time. Thanks anyway!